# Find largest subset in which all differences are divisible by $8$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Define $S$ as a set of $99$ natural numbers, i.e., $S\subset N$ and $|S| = 99$. Note that the maximum occurrence of an element in a set should be $1$, that is to say, elements are not allowed to be repeated.

Assume the elements in $S$ are unknown to us. We want to find a set $P \subset S$ such that $$\forall x,y \in P,\quad |x−y| ≡ 0\!\!\!\!\mod 8\quad \text{(the difference of $x$ and $y$ is divisible by 8)}$$What is the maximum possible size of $P$ for any set $S$ (note that the size of $S$ must be exactly $99$ while the elements can be any natural numbers)? That is to say, what is the value of $$\min S\subset N,|S|=99 \max P \subset S |P |\text{?}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **guarantee** $∀x,y ∈ P, |x−y| ≡ 0 \pmod 8$ for any arbitrary $S$, the largest such set can have $\left\lfloor\frac {99}8\right\rfloor+1=13$ elements since there are eight possible conjugacy classes and each conjugacy class will satisfy the required property.

Here's an example of a $(13\times 8=)104$ element $\tilde S$ where there is no such set with $14$ elements-
\begin{align*}
\{&8,16,24,\dots ,104\\
&9, 17, 25,\dots ,105\\
&10, 18, 26,\dots ,106\\
&.\\
&.\\
&.\\
&15, 23, 31,\dots ,113\}
\end{align*}
Any $99$ element subset $S\subset \tilde S$ does the job.

The proof is that any $x,y : |x−y| ≡ 0 \pmod 8$ must lie in the same line in the given diagram, and there are only $13$ elements in each line.

Comment: You sholud find an example where there is no such set with 14 elements in $P$.

Comment: @nonuser I can find such a set, but is it really necessary?

Comment: Well if you can not, then max is at least 14.

Comment: @nonuser yes, I think you are right. Please check the edit.

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest example by $S= \{1,2,3,4,.....,99\}$?  Then for a set to have $14$ elements we must consist entirely of elements of the form $8k + r$ for some $r:0\le r < 7$.  The absolute smallest such element to be possible in this set is $0k +r=r$ and the absolution greatest such element to be possible in this set is $12\cdot 8 + r = 96 + r$ and that is only possible if $r \le 3$. The only natural numbers of the for $8k+r$ so that $0+r \le 8k +r \le 12k + r$ are the ones where $k =0,...., 12$.  There are at most $13$ so elements.

Comment: @fleablood yes, of course! I had an idea and I stuck to it so much that I didn't realise this simplicity :(

Comment: "I had an idea and I stuck to it so much that I didn't realise this simplicity" We've all done that!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the elements of $S$ all have the same remainder modulo 8. In that case, the difference between any pairs of elements of $S$ is divisible by 8.

If $S$ is an arbitrary (finite) subset of $\mathbb{N}$, and you want to find the largest subset for which the difference between all elements is divisible by $8$: partition $S$ into the eight conjugacy classes modulo 8. The largest subset is then the largest conjugacy class.

Comment: $S$ should be arbitrary, not just the case you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I think elements in S are unknown, so it will not be the case that all elements are divisible by 8.

Comment: @John In that case, the technique in the second paragraph should give you the largest such subset.

Comment: But he doesn't want to find the largest subset of one particular $S$.  He wants to find want is the minimum size the largest such set has to be for *any* possible $S$.  For example we can't have the largest such set have $3$ elements because that would mean all the conjugacy classes are $3$ or less.  As there are at most $8$ conjugacy classes this means $S$ has at most $24$ elements.  But $S$ has $99$ so no matter what $S$ is, the largest such $P$ must have at least $4$ elements. (But that doesn't work either as that would mean $S$ has at most $32$ elements.)

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is such that $x-y$ is divisible by $8$ then $x\equiv y \pmod 8$ for any two elements or in other words, all $x\in P$ must have the same remainder, call it $r$ when divided by $8$.  There are only $8$ such possible remainders.  There are $99$ element so *on average* there are $\frac {99}8 = 12\frac 38$ elements for each possible remainder.  As it is impossible for all remainders to have fewer than average number elements, there must be at least one remainder with greater than average, or $13$ elements with that number of elements.

So the answer it thirteen.